# How can I differentiate the american R from the american W?

Tags: pronunciation

I followed some guides fro the pronunciation of the american R, as a result of which my R sounds just like a W. What is the difference between them?

Comment: You need to provide specific examples otherwise this question will be closed, [American takes a capital a]

Comment: What's your native language? Your first language is most probably interfering, there's a reason why we have the saying "you can't teach an old dog new tricks". After your 20s it's really difficult to sound like a native speaker in any language that is not your primary.

Comment: I don't think we can help much in this text based forum "r" is Alveolar approximant [ɹ] and w is a voiced labio-velar approximant [w]. But you would need to practice with audio.  Perhaps Monty Python is a good place to start.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OuALwLhUmKY

Comment: @Wistful I agree with most of the things you've said. Some thoughts: I think [ɹ] is pretty standard in General American as well as Received Pronunciation, so it is not "the American R". I didn't know it was a thing among some native speakers to render [ɹ] as [ʋ]. Wikipedia seems to suggest it is a South East English thing. That makes sense, as I don't think it occurs in American English to any noticeable degree. In baby talk [ɹ] is often rendered as [w]. As you say the initial [ɹ] is labialized and since [ʋ] is note completely labialized, I think the OP might actually be doing [w], not [ʋ].

Comment: I'm not sure whether you mean that you are pronouncing both of them the same, or whether you mean that you are pronouncing them differently but to your ear they sound the same.  Do they sound the same to native speakers?  Can people understand you when you say "red" and "ring" or do they think you've said "wed" and "wing"?  To my mind, adding a trill to the "r" would be preferable to pronouncing the "r" as /w/.

Comment: They sound the same to native speakers.